# List of tuples without forbidden pair

Tags: list-manipulation

How do you get a list of tuples in Mathematica that do not include certain pairs of elements? For example, I'm trying to list sequences of matrices of a certain length, and I do not want two adjacent elements in the sequence to be inverses of each other.

I suspect the code will end up looking like:

```
DropCases[Tuples[{a, b, Inverse[a], Inverse[a]}, 6], ???]
```

How do I do this in Mathematica?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

CORRECTED per input from RunnyKine

```
Length[Tuples[{a, b, Inverse[a], Inverse[a]}, 6]]
```

> 4096

```
Length[
 DeleteCases[
  DeleteCases[Tuples[{a, b, Inverse[a], Inverse[a]}, 6],
   {___, x_, Inverse[x_], ___}],
  {___, Inverse[x_], x_, ___}]]
```

> 1204

```
Length[
 DeleteCases[Tuples[{a, b, Inverse[a], Inverse[a]}, 6],
  {___, x_, Inverse[x_], ___} | {___, Inverse[x_], x_, ___}]]
```

> 1204

Comment: Thank you! Mathematica is incredible! Sorry to bother you again, but where is this documented? I searched around the Wolfram website for at least an hour before asking, and never saw (or recognized) the __ thing.

Comment: Look at documentation pages for `Pattern`, `Blank`, `BlankSequence`, and `BlankNullSequence`.

Answer (score 5):

Is your application time-critical? The first thing that comes into my *3:27-in-the-morning-mind* is to make a pattern that tests whether `a*b=1` (or with matrices `a.b==IdentityMatrix[n]`). Here is an example with numbers that should work for your matrices too when you adapt it

```
DeleteCases[
 Tuples[{1, 2, 1^-1, 2^-1}, 5], {___, x_, y_, ___} /; x*y === 1]
```

The output looks ok at the first glance.

Comment: OK, reading the answer of Bob I suspect you don't really want to use real matrices but keep the symbolic `a` and `b`...

Comment: +1. This looks fine to me. The OP didn't really state whether symbolic or numeric matrices is preferred.

Comment: If the list contains numeric matrices then the `Dot` product (x.y) would have to be an `IdentityMatrix` of appropriate dimensions.

Comment: This is neat, but I should have clarified that symbolic matrices are preferred in this case. Thanks for your input, though!